# Programming Mathematica - Introduction by Paul Wellin

Tags: programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice)

Can anyone recommend a decent book on programming mathematica ? I came across this which looks to be a more up to date version of a previous book by Paul Wellin.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programming-Mathematica-Introduction-Paul-Wellin/dp/1107009464/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1359499846&sr=8-1

Would also appreciate any comments on the previous version of this book by those who own it ? is a good book ? is the material covered in depth etc ?

Thanks
David.

Comment: Please see the linked duplicate question for books on _Mathematica_.

Comment: @rm-rf Sorry, but he is talking about a book which is not mentioned in the "Where can I find ..." link.

Comment: @David: I saw an early draft of that book and unfortunately I did not have time to proofread it, but YES, I can definitely recommend Paul Wellin. He does know Mathematica, he is a good teacher and I will just order that book now.

Comment: Thanks Rolf. I have had a look at the table of contents and the website for the book and its looks to be quite good.

Comment: @RolfMertig Sorry, but the book is mentioned in that list, albeit an earlier version. See "An introduction to programming with _Mathematica_" by Wellin, Gaylord and Kamin. Besides, the question here was "Can anyone recommend a decent book on programming mathematica?" and that link covers it adequately. This book wasn't in the list, because it was published in 2013 (to appear in Feb). I've now added it to the list.

Comment: I have already looked at the list of books recommended but it still doesn't answer whether the book is any good or not so it would be good to hear people views who have the older version so i see no reason to delete this post.